# Uploading an image for a thumbnail or category image is failing. Why?

Tags: magento2

I am on Magento 2.2.5. When I got to a category and try to upload a thumbnail or a category image it doesn't save. I hit upload, can see the image displayed, hit save and it is gone. I have no errors in the console or from Magento. I have tried multiple images in both jpg and png as well as different browsers. I have regenerated static content, reindexed and flushed the cache. When I try to go do a different category I get this error that I assume is related

```
Uncaught TypeError: value.map is not a function
at UiClass.setInitialValue (file-uploader.js:74)
at UiClass.initialize (abstract.js:73)
at UiClass.initialize (wrapper.js:109)
at new UiClass (class.js:49)
at Object.initComponent (layout.js:137)
at fire (jquery.js:3232)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3362)
at Object.deferred.(/admin/catalog/category/edit/key/009308a5b7762b4bfa04bfd90c973f56d60bf2e78fd7ff9602868d309be843c5/id/165/anonymous function) (/static/version1532616807/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery.js:3461:37)
at fire (jquery.js:3232)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3362)
```

Comment: pls check your permission folder, read more in here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html